# Rearranging data

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data that look like this:

```
head(t)
       sub   trialnum   block.x    lat.x      block.y  lat.y  diff
1       1       10          3      1355          5      1337   18
2       1       11          3      1324          5      1470 -146
3       1       12          3      1861          5      1690  171
4       1       13          3      3501          5      1473 2028
5       1       14          3      1566          5      1402  164
6       1       15          3      1380          5      1539 -159
```

What I would like to do is reformat the data in R such that the values of "trialnum" (there are 20 of them) are the new columns, "sub" is the row values, and each cell has the "diff" value. For example

```
          trialnum1      trialnum2      trialnum3...
sub
 1      
 2      
 3      
 .
 .
 .
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Although the answer is probably simple, I've been struggling with this problem for some time.

Comment: "diff" is a variable I've created by taking the difference between "lat.x" and "lat.y"

Comment: Probably be good if you stated that in the question.  Seems kind of important.

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you google "reshape r"? If so, what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I've tried (a) just various ways of aggregating the data and (b) reshape by doing dcast(data, sub ~ trialnum). The outcome of this function didn't put the "diff" values I need into the cells.

Comment: Use either the `tidyr` or `reshape2` packages. There are plenty of duplicate reshape questions on SO. Plus there are vignettes that you can find if you google them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape data from long to wide format R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r)

Answer (score 2):

Base package. We transpose column `diff` with the function `t(x)`, then create the desired column names.

```
df <- data.frame(t(t[, 7]))
# Using the trialnum column
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(t[2]), t[, 2])
# or just the number of rows
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(t[2]), 1:nrow(t))
```

Output:

```
   trialnum10 trialnum11 trialnum12 trialnum13 trialnum14 trialnum15
1         18       -146        171       2028        164       -159
  trialnum1 trialnum2 trialnum3 trialnum4 trialnum5 trialnum6
1        18      -146       171      2028       164      -159
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`, first get rid of the columns you don't want, then spread `trialnum` and `diff`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t %>% select(-block.x:-lat.y) %>%    # get rid of extra columns so t will collapse
    mutate(trialnum = paste0('trialnum', trialnum)) %>%    # fix values for column names
    spread(trialnum, diff)    # spread columns

#   sub trialnum10 trialnum11 trialnum12 trialnum13 trialnum14 trialnum15
# 1   1         18       -146        171       2028        164       -159
```

---

#### Data

```
t <- structure(list(sub = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trialnum = 10:15, 
                    block.x = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), lat.x = c(1355L, 1324L, 
                    1861L, 3501L, 1566L, 1380L), block.y = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                    5L, 5L), lat.y = c(1337L, 1470L, 1690L, 1473L, 1402L, 1539L
                    ), diff = c(18L, -146L, 171L, 2028L, 164L, -159L)), .Names = c("sub", 
               "trialnum", "block.x", "lat.x", "block.y", "lat.y", "diff"), row.names = c(NA, 
               -6L), class = "data.frame")
```